# How to multiply tuple values in array?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've tried everything to multiply the values in the tuple, but I get the error: TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'tuple' .

```
from itertools import product

arr = 0
val_x = []
val_y = []
n = int(input('n = '))

def multiply(product, *nums):
    factor = product
    for num in nums:
        factor *= num
    return factor

if __name__ == "__main__":

    for x in range(n ** 2):
        for y in range(n ** 2):
            if y == 0:
                arr += 1
        if arr == 1:
            val_x.append(bin(x)[2:].zfill(n))
            val_y.append(bin(x)[2:].zfill(n))
        arr = 0

    res = list(product(val_x, val_y))

    print(f'Input x,y = {res}')
    print(f'Output z = {multiply(*res)}')
```

The result I get is an array which contains tuples, for example [(00, 00), (00, 01)]. How do I multiply them so I get result of [(0000), (0000)] etc. When I run the script, for the last print, I get the error.

Comment: "so I get result of [(0000), (0000)] etc. " please provide the complete output you are expecting, this is not clear, and does not look like multiplication.

Comment: I need to multiply the values from my Input result, which are [(00, 00), (00, 01)], those are the values in binary. If I transform it, it gives [(0, 0), (0, 1)] . I need to make it multiply the values (0 * 0), (0 * 1).

Comment: Still not clear, do you want to multiply  _elementwise_ (i.e. the first element of the first tuple with the first element of the second tuple), or _tupleiwse_ (i.e. the first element of the first tuple with the second element of the first tuple)?

Comment: Also, I think that the fact that values are "in binary" is irrelevant, that's just a display issue.

Comment: First element in the first tuple with the second element in the first tuple. I have X and Y value in each tuple. [(X1, Y1), (X2, Y2)] I need to multiply X1 * Y1 and X2 * Y2 and so on for each tuple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your description in comments, you need to change `multiply()`.
In the following implementation, `multiply()` receives a list of tuples and returns a list by multiplying all elements of each tuple in input list. It is required to cast `str` to `int` before multiplication. The output of `multiply()` is a list of integers, you can convert integers to binary representation if needed.

```
from itertools import product

arr = 0
val_x = []
val_y = []
n = int(input('n = '))

def multiply(res):
    output = []
    for i in res:
        output.append(int(i[0], 2)*int(i[1], 2))
    return output

if __name__ == "__main__":

    for x in range(n ** 2):
        for y in range(n ** 2):
            if y == 0:
                arr += 1
        if arr == 1:
            val_x.append(bin(x)[2:].zfill(n))
            val_y.append(bin(x)[2:].zfill(n))
        arr = 0

    res = list(product(val_x, val_y))
    print(f'Input x,y = {res}')
    print(f'Output z = {multiply(res)}')
```

sample for `n=2`:

```
n = 2
Input x,y = [('00', '00'), ('00', '01'), ('00', '10'), ('00', '11'), ('01', '00'), ('01', '01'), ('01', '10'), ('01', '11'), ('10', '00'), ('10', '01'), ('10', '10'), ('10', '11'), ('11', '00'), ('11', '01'), ('11', '10'), ('11', '11')]
Output z = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 2, 4, 6, 0, 3, 6, 9]
```